# Categorizing a photo as a selfie

Tags: camera, artificial-intelligence

How to recognize categorize a photo into selfie category ?

I was wondering if we could use the meta data where in it contains the type of the camera used to snap a pic (It could be a front camera of a phone (secondary camera) in case of a selfie but not necessarily should be, primary camera (back camera of the phone) could also be used or the non phone camera could be used too)

Do we use AI techniques to learn it as a selfie, Or do we use some kind of measuring the focal length to recognize the given pic as selfie.

This is just a open ended question. Any comments or thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Meta data wouldn't be useful as smart phones are becoming so advanced. I know Apple and Microsoft have both shot commercials with their phones, as well using photos for giant billboards.

You could probably find some facial recognition software that cameras use to find faces without a lot of difficulty (opencv is a place to look). From there you could measure the size of the face in relation to the photo, if it's large enough it's probably a selfie.

Answer (score 1):

With the selfie stick, categorize a photo as a selfie by the size of the face is probably not the most accurate solution. Of course, if you think that no photo that you have will be used with a selfie stick, then as roro said, measuring the size of the face would be a working solution.

What I would suggest is to have a photo of the owner of the phone and try to estimate with facial recognition if the photo contains the owner.